# Enable foreign key constraint of sqlite DB from php script

Tags: php, sqlite

I am trying to enable foreign key constraint of sqlite database from my php script.

I tried :

```
shell_exec('sqlite ex.db');

shell_exec('PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON');

echo $isEnabled = shell_exec('PRAGMA foreign_keys');
```

But I am not getting `$isEnabled` as `1` . In fact I am not getting anything as output.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why you dont use the built-in SQLite driver?

```
$con = new SQLite3('ex.db');
$con->exec('PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;');
var_dump($con->query('PRAGMA foreign_keys;')->fetchArray());
```

According your problem: `shell_exec()` (as the name suggest) executes shell commands. This means, that you try to execute three (!) shell commands, but you want to execute one and then you want to execute 2 more commands within the interactive sqlite3-process you started before. This is not possible this way. Maybe you can play around with `stdin`, but because PHP comes with SQLite3-support I don't see a reason to make it more complex, that it needs to be.

Comment: Should work with PDO_SQLite too, because the queries are sent as they are. Even the method names (`exec()`/`queryy()`) are the same ;) Only the return value of `query()` is a little bit different, but makes it even easier: `query('PRAGMA foreign_keys')->fetchColumn(0);`

Comment: Thanks KingCrunch, just for my another new app where I am using codeigniter with sqlite3 ....where all db connection set up are at database.php :$active_group = "default";
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = $appip;
$db['default']['username'] = "";
$db['default']['password'] = "";
$db['default']['database'] = "sqlite:ex.db";
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = "pdo";
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = "";
 and so on...how can i still enable foreign keys? Thanks again...I posted same que on CI forums also but no reply yet..:-(

Comment: please note that I am using  $this->{$this->db_group_name}->query('PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;')   in my model constructor

Answer (score 0):

From [sqlite command line shell tutorial](http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html) there is a section Using sqlite3 in a shell script:

> When the sqlite3 program is launched with two arguments, the second
>   argument is passed to the SQLite library for processing, the query
>   results are printed on standard output in list mode, and the program
>   exits.

So you could try `sqlite3 ex.db 'PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON; PRAGMA foreign_keys'`